# Vuetify access Vue instance data with v-for in v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to access the Vue instance data using v-for inside Vuetify's v-data-table

Issue: Data not displayed under Table Header 2

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="tabular.table" :hide-actions="true"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props" v-for="(table, index) in tabular.table" >
        <td :class="{'warn' : warning(index)}">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td v-for="inner in table.inner" :class="{'warn' : !inner.data}">{{ props.item.inner.data }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>

tabular:{table: [
        {
          name: 'Table Data 1',
          inner: [{data: "false"}]
        }
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/m09uLgaz/1/

Comment: you set the table's `inner.data` with a string `"false"`. Try to change with a boolean: `inner: [{ data: false }]`

Comment: I tried it, Table Header 2 still does not display data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use

```
<template v-slot:items="props" v-for="(table, index) in tabular.table">
    <td :class="{'warn' : warning(index)}">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
    <td v-for="inner in props.item.inner" :class="{'warn' : !inner.data}">{{ inner }}</td>
</template>
```

Instead of

```
<td v-for="inner in table.inner" :class="{'warn' : !inner.data}">{{ props.item.inner.data }}</td>
```

You don't need to use **props.item.inner** because you have that reference in **inner**. Also in the object *inner* use true and false as Boolean and not as string.

Edited JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/0pw3264a/

Updated fiddle for custom sort https://jsfiddle.net/qtLujh0e/

Comment: The data is coming now but the sorting does not work. Why is it so?

Comment: Because the element is not of a primitive type when we access it through the object property. For the table its still an object. You have to use **custom-sort** prop to sort that column

Comment: Can you please update the fiddle with it? No idea of the custom-sort prop

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to show custom sort. Please accept the answer if it answers your original question

Comment: Also please try to go through the documentation before asking these type of question or in the future it might not be well received.